# How to get POST data from request?

Tags: python, django, post

I just set up  an apache server with django, and to test it, made a very simple function in views.py

```
channel = rabbit_connection()
@csrf_protect
@csrf_exempt
def index(request): 
    data={'text': 'Food truck is awesome! ', 'email': 'bob@yahoo.com', 'name': 'Bob'}
    callback(json.dumps(data))   
    context = RequestContext(request)    
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=context)
```

This function works fine if I send a `GET` or `POST` request to the server.  However I would like to get this data from `POST` request. Assuming I send request like this:

```
import pycurl
import simplejson as json

data = json.dumps({'name':'Bob', 'email':'bob@yahoo.com', 'text': u"Food truck is awesome!"})

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://ec2-54-......compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.html')
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, data)
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)

for i in range(100):
    c.perform()
```

What I would like to have in the view is something like this:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
     data = ?????? # Something that will return me my dictionary
```

Just in case:
     It is always will be in JSON format and the fields are unknown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data= request.POST.get('data','')`

Will return you a single value (key=`data`) from your dictionary. If you want the entire dictionary, you simply use `request.POST`. You are using the QueryDict class here:

> In an HttpRequest object, the GET and POST attributes are instances of django.http.QueryDict. QueryDict is a dictionary-like class customized to deal with multiple values for the same key. This is necessary because some HTML form elements, notably , pass multiple values for the same key.
>
> QueryDict instances are immutable, unless you create a copy() of them. That means you can’t change attributes of request.POST and request.GET directly.

-[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)

Comment: Hi @JcKelley, as far as I understand the above statement will get the values for data ? correct? But I don't have value data in my JSON

Comment: That will grab you key value from the dictionary. So `name = request.POST.get('name','')` will return the `name` variable "Bob"

Comment: Exactly, but how to return the whole dictionary?

Comment: request.POST will return a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

If the data posted is in JSON format, you need to deserialize it:

```
import simplejson
myDict = simplejson.loads(request.POST.get('data'))
```